# how to show message box in windows store app when wcf data service update record successfully?

Tags: windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store app. I am using WCF data service and I want to give friendly message to user that we are done with updating record.

This is my function where updating is done.

I want to put message that "Update successfully".

```cs
private void ModfityJobsAsynchCallBack(IAsyncResult synchresult)
{
    try
    {
        dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                _context.EndSaveChanges(synchresult);
                this.IsDataLoaded = false;
            });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("Error while updating data");
        msgDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: question is, where should i put the Message Dialog, for "updated successfully" in above code

Answer (score 0):

after the line saying `this.IsDataLoaded = false;`
the anonymous function you pass in to be executed async will be executed in different thread. your Try{}Catch{} here only catches errors in putting this function in UI thread's queue and not it's execution result.

```
private void ModfityJobsAsynchCallBack(IAsyncResult synchresult)
{
    try
    {
        dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                     _context.EndSaveChanges(synchresult);
                     this.IsDataLoaded = false;
                     await Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Success").ShowAsync();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                      await Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Fail").ShowAsync();
                }
            });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog("Error while updating data");
        msgDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you rewrite my code using BEST practice? and message box for failed and sucess

Comment: this is how I think it should be, but didn't put it into VS to see how it behaves. as your anonymous method is already going to be in UI thread, you won't need any dispatcher